# Low-quality posts tool keeps giving me items I voted 'Not Sure' on

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

Using the [Low Quality Posts Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/), I have already said `Not Sure` to these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11913294/538216
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3110931/538216

But they keep coming back to me in the queue. Seems to me it's a bug.

Comment: Or maybe they want you to make a decision

Comment: If "not sure" were called "skip", that behavior would make more sense.

Comment: I have no clue about PHP code, so I would likely click "Not Sure" as well on the second example. What's the point of asking me again? I still don't know what the code does, if anything.

Comment: This is a bug. Others have reported it as well, and we're still working on tracking it down.

Comment: @Levi We reproduced and fixed the issue causing you to see [the post in your first bullet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11913294/538216) multiple times: a small fraction of review items are "fake" tasks for the purpose of auditing reviewers. If you clicked "Not Sure" on an audit task, it was possible to see it again. We still haven't cracked the second case though. From the logs, we see that you were given the post to review 3 times, but it *appears* as if you navigated away to the corresponding question page, rather than reviewing it, the first two times. We'll continue to investigate it.

Comment: @Emmett That may have been possible.  I sometimes open the question to get more context than is provided.  I may have never taken an action.  Good to see at least one was a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.

A small fraction of review items are "fake" tasks for the purpose of auditing reviewers, and there was a bug in which clicking <kbd>Not Sure</kbd> on an audit task did not always dequeue it from your list.